# Infering variable type from text file

Tags: scala, types

I have a csv text file that stores the variable names, their types and values, example below:

```
name, String, Matt
age, Int, 24
cash, Long, 3000
```

Based on this params I want to fill a case class:

```
case class Person(name: String, age:Int, cash: Long)
```

What I am trying to do is to create a map of variableName -> value in its correct type, ie.

```
name -> "Matt", age -> 24, cash -> 3000L
```

I can read all the fields as Strings, so the tuple (name, type,value) consists of ("age", "Int", "24"). 
The only solution I came up with so far was to write long and messy factory method, the idea is described here:

```
val longStr: String = "Long"
val intStr: String = "Int"
// .... other types
tuple match {
  case (name, `longStr`, value) => (name -> value.toLong)
  case (name, `intStr`, value) => (name -> value.toInt)
// ... other matches
}
```

Is there any better way of achieving this?

Is there a relatively easy way to skip reading type from text file and infer it from the case class?

Comment: I think you asked this already in a deleted question  and the comments there still apply. We need to know more about your use-case. What do you expect the value returned from your match to be? Each `case` returns a different type. How will you use that value? What happens if the file is wrong and contains e.g. `age, String, 24`? If it is never wrong, what's the value in storing the type there?

Comment: Dropped the firsts question since it was a bit wrong and I tried to rewrite it here. Generally what I wans is to put data from txt file to case class and I am trying to find any solution. The map entried I am receiving from this pattern match should are treated as a String->Object mappings and later e.g. for a case class field age I am doing `age = map.get("age")`

Comment: I still don't get why you feel this is a good design. Since every key has a fixed associated type, and you need to know the key name you want in order to pass it to the case class constructor, what are you gaining here?